# Encountered Strange Error: " & ErrorName

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

New to VisualStudio 2015, but not to programming.  Have searched both Google and here for a lead on this, but considering the available search terms, I might not immediately uncover them.

I was looking into porting an old VB6 (200k+ LoC) to VB.Net in VS2015.  Mostly just poking around to determine viability.  Using a project converter, and have resolved most of the initial errors, and am familiar with how the Error List works.

However, it is throwing a new one at me.  It now only has two lines of error, both showing the same thing.  They both say:

" & ErrorName

That's a Quote, Ampersand, and ErrorName.  That's all that show up on the error list line.  No file.  No line number.  Double click on them does nothing.

I thought perhaps the project was corrupted, so I completely re-created it, adding all the modules, forms, classes, etc again, and it found a lot more errors to fix, which I fixed, and now these two lines show up again.

Does anyone have any indication where this is coming from, or, better yet, how to fix?

Comment: you might do a global search for `ErrorName`

Comment: Believe me I have.

Comment: FWIW most of the VB6 converters I have seen just produce VB.NET code that compiles.  It isnt is the least optimized for ,NET, which is a low hurdle.  It will still have scads of things like ReDim Preserve` rather than a proper NET collection.  Its all to be expected, but still worth noting

Comment: As this is a 'recreational' endeavor, i was using VS2008 for free conversion, lacking any other in the same price bracket..  followed up by a VS2015 upgrade.  As VS2008 failed to convert it, i did it in about 8 subsets of modules, each of which converted alright, but left tremendous busywork.  Still cheaper than $7,000 to just get in the door at vbmigration.

Comment: I would add, its only a fragmented message.  Normal error messages have real text, describe the error, and might pull a snippet of code.  This is just what is written above.  Dont know if its a bug in VS2015 or what...

Comment: Perhaps try the it in an earlier version of VS? Like 2013 or maybe even 2010? [**You could also report the problem to the VS developers**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/05/05/the-easiest-way-to-file-bugs-and-send-error-logs-for-visual-studio-2015/).

Comment: I was under the impression the VS2008->2015 upgrade was one way...  If i couldnt upgrade all the way to 2k15, im not sure id bother.  I might try the VS developers, though, thanks.

Comment: `i did it in about 8 subsets of modules, each of which converted alright, but left tremendous busywork.` Does this mean that you got it to an error free state under VS2008, but on upgrading to 2015 you have new error messages?

Comment: No.  Immediately imported all into VS2015 and copied each object into the main proj before discarding the extra projects.  Left a couple days busywork removing all the extra stuff it put in because it couldnt find various calls.

Comment: I'm no fan VS2015, just to many bugs reported on it.  If you haven't yet, I'd add a project reference to 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.dll' as the VB2008 upgrade relied on that heavily.  You will probably get warnings about any references to it as being obsolete though.

Comment: @TnTinMn : I'm no fan of VS2012+, but that's because I think they look too ugly. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen VB programmers report this misbehavior before, never with a good lead to explain the problem.  It is specific to VS2015, the Roslyn integration caused many issues.  In general a very buggy release, be sure to apply all available Updates, currently up to Update 3.  If you have a license that includes an MSDN subscription then I recommend you install VS2012, the last "good" version of VS that was not yet affected by Microsoft's new focus on agile development.

I *think* the underlying issue is caused by the IDE simply not parsing the compiler error message correctly.  Probably having to do with the statement with the error getting quoted in the message.  Getting only part of the statement text and it fumbling quotes is a pretty good hint that this is where it went wrong.

So look at the actual output of the compiler, decent odds you'll now see the full error text.  Use Tools > Options > Project and Solutions > Build and Run.  Change the "MSBuild output build output verbosity" setting to Normal.  After the failed build, use View > Output to see the compiler output.  You'll probably have a lot of messages, consider copy/pasting the content.

Comment: Best advice.  Thanks.  While i had done a bit of seaching, I didnt realize it was a fragment of my code it was displaying.  I changed every instance of 'ErrorName' to have a separate prefix and it changed the message.  just commenting out the ones still affected and going from there.  Its the right answer because it is simply a buggy IDE.  I felt that from the get go of using it, just didt realize the VS versions before it were not so transient.